# Cocoa NSFileHandle is alway nil on existing file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I created a file with text in it. Now I want to append to the file.

```
if ( [fm fileExistsAtPath: userLogTextFile] ) {
    NSFileHandle * file;
    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: userLogTextFile];
    NSData  *   dataBuffer = [NSData dataWithBytes: [outputLine UTF8String] length: [outputLine length]];
    if ( nil == file ) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open file");
    } else {
        ....
    }
```

The file variable is always nil after the call to fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath. Even though I've used fm (NSFileManager defaultManager) to check the existence.

How do append my data to the existing text file?

Comment: What's the file? Are the permissions correct?

Comment: The file path is absolute /Users/<username>/Documents/data/file.csv<br/>I opend the file with o765 which is rwxrw-r-x. The addendum text is just data for a cvs file.